# UIScrollView with multiple multi-line labels and AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel

Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried literally everything and nothing has worked for me yet.

**So basically what i want to do is the following:** I have a scroll view with some labels in it. All the labels get their text from a server and I have set their number of lines to 0 so that they change their height according to the amount of text. However, this does not affect the scrollview content size(even though my labels have constraints set up to the bottom,top,leading and trailing of the scrollview) and the labels go off screen and I am unable to scroll down. Can someone point me in the right direction to how I would set up my constraints, my view hierarchy and etc?

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you try to fit content size after loaded label text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using `UITableView` instead, it has several benefits:

1. It allows for reuse of cells, if all the cells look the same
2. It manages recycling of cells when the number of values you're getting from the server increases (decreases memory pressure when number of cells becomes substantial)
3. It allows for more flexibility with the content (it's quite often for design to change last second or to evolve over the course of the project)
4. Most importantly, `UITableView` support auto sizing cells (as of iOS8), you need to specify the constraints between the label and the borders of the cell

There are several resources to start with:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout
- https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells
- http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Answer (score 1):

Late, but this solved it for me:

1. Set leading (I have a 32pt inset), trailing and top constraints. The trailing will not actually seemingly do anything..
2. Make the trailing `Greater Than or Equal` to avoid localization alert.
3. Finally, add a new `Equal Width` constraint to the label matching the scrollview. Use the constant to subtract the required padding (I used 64 due to mirror my leading inset).

And voilà! The Label will align correctly both in IB and in-app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a container view in a scrollView
2. Add constraints to superview (leading, trailing, top, bottom, height,width)
3. Make IBOutlet of constraints that you are going to update.
4. Add you all labels inside that view.
5. Update constrains/frame of your label so that it fits the text.
6. How much you increase the label height you should increase the container height too.
7. If the label count is not fixed use custom label class to add subview.

Perhaps you should need to understand how ScrollView works in Storyboard with autolayout.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now, sorry for not making it clear, unfortunately it does not work with the auto-resizing (setting number of lines to 0) of the label.

Comment: Send your updated code. It should work. You have not mentioned that you are using container view inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

In Scrollview the **last view's bottom constraint** is so important. You should set its **priority to 250** and put it to **Greater than or equal**.

[image]

Remember you should only change the bottom constraint of the **last view**, which in my case it's the continue button.